# Set value on SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, database

I have 2 data transfer sql statements being run and sent to the same table.

SqlBuldCopy1 returns column NAME||AGE||CAT

SqlBuldCopy2 returns column NAME||AGE

Is it possible to set up a default value of "ALL" to column CAT in SqlBulkCopy2?

```
DataReader dr = command.ExcecuteReader();
SqlBulkCopy myCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(SQLconnection);
myCopy.DestinationTableName = "Customer";    
myCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
myCopy.BatchSize = 5000;
myCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you are specifying to be executed in your command.ExecuteReader, you can modify the query such that "ALL" is defined as the CAT column.

Sort of:

```
SELECT Name, Age, 'ALL' as CAT
FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 2):

For SQLBulkCopy2 you could change the select statement behind the dr DataReader to select out the literal "ALL" for cat e.g.

```
select NAME, AGE, 'ALL' CAT from  . . .
```

Or alternatively, implement the `IDataReader` interface in a class that wraps your DataReader, and provides a third column that always returns all.

On that note, I've built a CustomDataReader class that implement IDataReader. You initialise the class with an `IEnumerable<T>`, and add "Columns" to the class. Each column has a name, a data type (Column Type), and a lambda `Func<T, CT>` that takes a T and returns Column Type, basically the lambda knows how to get the column value out of the T item. 
The classes Read() method moves to the next item in the `IEnumerable<T>`, the `GetValue()` methods call the lambdas passing in the current item. Read returns false when the iterator MoveNext returns false for the Enumerator your got from the `IEnumerable<T>`.

It's actually quite straight forward to do, and is very handy for consuming odd things like files and feeds from message queues directly into `SqlBulkCopy` without first building them into `DataTable`'s in memory. It's also quite handy for passing existing object graphs to `SqlBulkCopy` without preformatting them as data tables. I'd post the code but the company owns it now, sorry . . .

Hope this helps.